# how to save data from textboxes to database on submit button click using php

Tags: php, html, mysqli

i need to transfer the data from textboxes designed in HTML to Mysql database using php. I tried a lot but didnt work...so finally if anyone has a working code already for it then please let me know.
i just have two textboxes named "username" and "password" and a submit button.
I have already created a db [dbname: userdemo, tablename: users] but no results. Please use OOPs concept not procedural.
Any kind of help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: What have you tried so far, do you have some examples of your code you've tried?

Comment: `I tried a lot but didnt work` .. What exactly have you tried ? `Please use OOPs concept not procedural. ` this is not a code writing service.

Comment: *"Please use OOPs concept not procedural."* - That's quite the order. Anything else you'd like us to do, like mow your lawn, walk your dog, go to the supermarket, and pick up your dry cleaning? *sigh*

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller chunks (retrieving values from textboxes, encrypting the password data, sending it to a php backend, putting it into a table record) and see for yourself where you get stuck. Once you have some code, maybe we can help you on any of these **concrete** coding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html code below is a snippet of how your form should look, though you have mentioned you already have this part done:

page1.html

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
  <input type="text" name="usernameForm">
  <input type="password" name="passwordForm">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The php code below then obtains the variables from page1.html after a user Submits their information from the form, and then inserts a line into a table in the database. When using this code, don't forget to replace all the table names, columns, etc with the ones you have on your form, as well as the 4 "********" variables that give your code access to your database:

page2.php

```
//uses MySQL (PDO)
<?php
$usernameForm = $_POST['usernameForm'];
$passwordForm = $_POST['passwordForm'];

$servername = "********";
$username = "********";
$password = "********";
$myDB = "********";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$myDB", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully"; 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO myTable (username, password) VALUES (:usernameForm, :passwordForm)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(':usernameForm', $usernameForm);
    $stmt->bindParam(':passwordForm', $passwordForm);
    $stmt->execute();

    }
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

$conn = NULL;
?>
```

---

**Edited:** After having read your comment on wanting to have all this code on one page, a simple way of doing it is the following:

Replace this line:

```
<form method="POST" action="page2.php">
```

with this line:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>">
```

What is happening here is the following:
PHP code is always run on the server. When you have your website fully loaded, your connection with the server terminated. Whatever information you are sending to the server via the `<form>...</form>` tags need to establish a connection with the server, which is why in general people user two pages (one for the input, and another one that receives the data), **HOWEVER** there is a simple and common way of keeping all this code in one page: have the `<form>...</form>` send to itself!

To do this you have 2 options:

1. if your page was called page1.php, then you could just replace `action="page2.php"` with `action="page1.php"`. However this in general is not good programming because if for some reason the name of your page changes, then your code breaks, which leads us to the second (and better) option.
2. replacing `action="page2.php"` with `action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>"`. What this does is almost the same as option 1, HOWEVER the php code inside `action` is asking the $_SERVER superglobal for what the name of the page is, hence preventing your page from "breaking" in cases like when you rename your file.

Comment: @Webeng...Hey thanks for the script above...it worked....!!! But here we used two different files page1.html as well page2.php what i was asking was to run it in single php file...i mean the html form as well as the php logic in single file.....!!!How to do that(but using $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname); connection string and not "PDO")

Comment: @user3205084 Hi user! I edited my answer including how to have the code in one single file, however I didn't change the PDO part for 2 reasons. 1, because it's the only style of MySQL I know enough of to make reasonably good code :), and 2 because it is the most recommended form of MySQL due to functionality in general, so whenever I have the chance, I tend to recommend using PDO over other styles of MySQL.

Comment: @Tjeetu no problem dude! glad I could help